# Scipy curve_fit crashing when attempting to curve fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

am trying to fit a function to some data. However I run into a problem where I am getting a message `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt return 1/(np.sqrt(x*a+1))`. Offcoures I suspect that it's due to a negative value under the square root, however I don't have negative values in any of my data. But when I changed the functions argument to `abs()` the problem was gone. **So it seems like scipi want's a fit with a negative value of the parameter `a` but then crashes when it tries to use it?!**

My code and the data which I use are as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

omega = np.array([10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120, 10240, 20480, 40960, 81920, 163840, 327680, 655360, 1310720])*2*np.pi
U_out = np.array([5.08, 5.12, 5.12, 5.12, 5.08, 5, 4.76, 4.04, 2.76, 1.58, 0.860, 0.460, 0.260, 0.104, 0.054, 0.032, 0.0144, 0.0065])
U_in = np.array([5.20, 5.20, 5.20, 5.20, 5.20, 5.6, 5.6, 5.4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5 ,5 ,5 ,5, 5])

trans = U_out/U_in
trans_ucrt =  (trans*0.03)*1/np.sqrt(2)

def func_1T(x,a):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(x*a+1))

def trans_func_fit():
    #Dodanie punktów danych na wykresie
    plt.scatter(omega, trans, color='steelblue')
    plt.errorbar(omega, trans, yerr=trans_ucrt, fmt='--o')

    #Dopasowanie wykresu do funckcji
    w_omega = np.array(omega) # x-Variable
    transmisivity = np.array(trans) # y-Variable
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_1T, w_omega, transmisivity)
    perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    y = func_1T(w_omega, *popt)

    #Stylistyka i wygląd wykresu
    plt.plot(w_omega, y, '--', color = 'g', label="Dopasowanie dla: $a={:.3f}\pm{:.3f}$" .format(popt[0], perr[0]))
    plt.legend(['Dane pomiarowe połączone linią przerywaną --'], loc='upper right')
    plt.xlabel(r'Częstość $\omega$')
    plt.ylabel(r'Transmitancja filtru $T$')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.grid(True, which="both")
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=10))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, subs='all', numticks=100))
    plt.show()
trans_func_fit()
```

So in short I would like to know what causes this error, as there are no negative values in the arrays. All help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a `RuntimeWarning` is not really a crash. Your code does produce sensible return values for `popt, pcov`.

This warning occurs because your function `func_1T` is not defined for negative `a`, but `curve_fit` doesn't know that. Try restricting the domain for `a` like this:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_1T, w_omega, transmisivity, bounds=(0, np.inf))
```

This way, no warning is produced as the function won't try to explore values of `a` for which the function is not defined.